# Convert datetime.date or string to timestamp in python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timestamp

I am aware that this question was posted more times before but yet I have few doubts. I have a `datetime.date` (ex. `mydate = date(2014,5,1)`) and I converted this as a string, then saved in DB as a column `(dtype:object)` in a table. Now I wanted to change the storage of dates from text to timestamp in DB. I tried this,

Ex. My table is `tab1`. I read this as dataframe `df` in python.

```
# datetime to timestamp
df['X'] = pd.to_datetime(mydate)
```

When I check dtype in python editor  `df.info()`, the dtype of X is datetime64[ns] but when I save this to DB in MySQL and read again as dataframe in python, the dtype changes as object. I have datatype as datetime in MySQL but I need this as timestamp datatype in MySQL. Is there any way to do it? Also, I need only date from `Timestamp('2014-5-01 00:00:00')` and exclude time.

Comment: Is your column in MySQL of Date type?

Comment: In MySQL, it is datetime

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when u read the serialized value from MySQL the python MySQL connector does not convert it. you have to convert it to DateTime value after reading data from the cursor by calling your function again on retrieved data:

```
df['X'] = pd.to_datetime(df['col'])
```

Comment: Ok, but I want to have datatype as timestamp in MySQL instead of datetime. (displaying only date)

Comment: So select TIMESTAMP type in MySQL as the column type...

Comment: Any idea of how I can do this through python?

Comment: Have you checked  df['datetime'] = df['datetime'].apply(lambda x: pd.Timestamp(x))?

Comment: Yes, I just tried using pd.Timestamp, but still the datatype in MySQL is datetime :(

Comment: Without changing the type of that column to timestamp you will not get timestamp

Answer (score 0):

As suggested, I changed the column type directly by using `dtype` argument in `to_sql()` function while inserting into the database. So, now I can have datatypes as `TIMESTAMP, DATETIME` and also `DATE` in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

such works for me:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
df['timestamp'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda x:  x.timestamp())
```